# ASC outputs for Circuitscape don't work

Tags: raster, gdal, reclassify, ascii

I'm preparing a raster layer of combined resistances of landcover, roads and rail and a second raster layer of 'focal nodes' for a Circuitscape Analysis. I prepped the files in R and they look fine in ArcGIS.

But, when I convert my .tif files to .asc, I get this error and then subsequently, Circuitscape does not run when I input them in the software.

```
gdal_translate('Prot_Areas_all1.tif', 'Prot_Areas_CS.asc', of='AAIGrid', 
FORCE_CELLSIZE=TRUE)

Warning 1: Producing a Golden Surfer style file with DX and DY instead
of CELLSIZE since the input pixels are non-square.  Use the
FORCE_CELLSIZE=TRUE creation option to force use of DX for
even though this will be distorted.  Most ASCII Grid readers
(ArcGIS included) do not support the DX and DY parameters.
```

Circuitscape throws up an error saying 'Raster headers do not match'.

My R skills are pretty rough, so I don't really understand the exact problem I'm facing either.

This is a part of the code I was using for one of the 'Focal Nodes' Raster file:

```
 #Converting Protected Areas shape file to .asc for circuitscape
 #First convert to raster and then to .asc
 Prot_Areas <- readOGR(*shapefile from my drive*)
 b<-bbox(Boundary_transform) #retrieving spatial boundaries from our project 
 boundary
 r<- raster(nrow = 500, ncol = 500, xmn= b[1,1], xmx= b[1,2], ymn= b[2,1], 
 ymx= b[2,2])
 Prot_Areas_transform <- spTransform(Prot_Areas, ll) #ll here is the UTM Zone 
 44 projection
 Prot_Areas_raster <- rasterize(Prot_Areas_transform,r)
 plot(Prot_Areas_raster)
 Prot_Areas_raster

 #Recalssify all to one value= 1 (these are the focal nodes- which must be 
 equal in value)
 m <- c(1, 15 , 1) 
 rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
 Prot_Areas_rc <- reclassify(Prot_Areas_raster, rclmat)
 plot(Prot_Areas_rc)

 # resample to make the same resolution as Land Use Land cover (this is the UTM Zone 44 proj, and 100X100 resolution
 Prot_Areas_reasmpled<-resample(Prot_Areas_rc, LULC_rc, method="ngb")
 plot(Prot_Areas_reasmpled)
 writeRaster(Prot_Areas_reasmpled, 'Prot_Areas_all1.tif', overwrite=T)

 #Creating the .asc file for Circuitscape
 gdal_translate('Prot_Areas_all1.tif', 'Prot_Areas_CS.asc', of='AAIGrid', 
 FORCE_CELLSIZE=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of the resistances and the focal node files have to be the same. By default if you create rasters from datasets with different geographic extents, the resulting raster grids will have different numbers of columns and rows.  The way around this is to reclassify your resistance data to the NODATA value -9999, then use  a tool such as Cell Statistics (maximum) to overlay your focal nodes data (with positive integer values) over the resistance data.  The you end up with a focal nodes file that has the same geographic footprint (and thus grid dimensions) as the resistance file.

You can check this by right-clicking on the layer in catalog and going to properties... you should see the same number of rows and columns in both files